# Control de validacion de formulario flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Tengo este control en mi boton antes de enviar una solicitud a una api, el control funciona bien, cuando entrar en algun if aparece un dialog mostrando el mensaje correspondiente ,pero si entro a algun if y entonces preciono el boton para ir a la pagina anterior, me aparece de nuevo el dialog con el ultimo mensaje y no regresa a la pagina anterior, como puedo solucionarlo?

```
ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          String mensaje = "";
          bool bandera = false;
          if(_correoController.text == ''){
            mensaje = "No ha ingresado un correo valido";
            bandera = true;
          }
          else if(_passwordController.text == ''){
            mensaje = "No ha ingresado una contraseña";
            bandera = true;
          }
          else if(_linkController.text == ''){
            mensaje = "No ha ingresado un Codigo Link";
            bandera = true;
          }
          else if(_medidorController.text == ''){
            mensaje = "No ha ingresado el medidor";
            bandera = true;
          }
          else if( _passwordController.text != _passwordConfirmationController.text ){
            mensaje = "La confirmacion de la contraseña no es igual que la original";
            bandera = true;
          }
          if (bandera == false){
            cargandoDialog(context);
            String respuestaCrearCuenta = await usuario.altaUsuario(_correoController.text, _passwordController.text, 
                                                                    _linkController.text, _medidorController.text);    
            _mostrarDialogMensaje(respuestaCrearCuenta, context);
          }
          else{
            _mostrarDialogMensaje(mensaje, context);
          }
        },
        child: Text('Crear Cuenta', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          shape: StadiumBorder(),
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 20),  
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: asegurate que la variable bandera la conviertas a false cuando termine. También asegurate que estés cerrando el antiguo mensaje antes de abrir uno nuevo .

Answer (score 0):

```
TextFormField(
                            onChanged: (_) {
                              setState(() {
                                if (Control.text.isNotEmpty) {
                                  _formKeyHome.currentState!.validate();
                                }
                              });
                            },
                            controller: Control,
                            validator: (value) {
                              if (Invalido) {
                                Invalido = false;

                             
                              }
                              if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                       
                                return 'Campo obligatorio';
                              }
                              return null;
                            },
                            
                            
    ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                if (_formKeyHome.currentState!.validate()) {
                                  setState(() {
                                           Invalido = true;
                                          });
                                        }
                                      });
```

Comment: Hola Willian, Mira [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para evitar votos negativos y/o que tu repuesta sea eliminada.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo este código responde a la pregunta. Lee [answer].